# No route matches [GET] "/price.txt"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an error when make a link to the file:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/price.txt"

    #view
        <div class="container" id = "prices">
            <div class="row center-block">
                    <a type="button" id="get-price" class="btn btn-success button-get-price" 
                    href="<%= asset_path('price.txt') %>">Get price!</a>    
            </div>  
        </div>

#routes
        root 'static_pages#home'
          match '/',          to: 'static_pages#home',       via: 'post'
          match '/manager',   to: 'static_pages#manager',    via: 'get'
          match '/signin',    to: 'sessions#new',            via: 'get'
          match '/signout',   to: 'sessions#destroy',        via: 'delete'
          match '/manager',   to: 'static_pages#manager',    via: 'edit'
          match '/manager',   to: 'static_pages#manager',    via: 'update'
```

But when I rename `price.txt` file in my public folder and in view file to `1.txt`, everything is ok.

Whats wrong?
Thanks

Comment: where are you keeping price.txt? can you also paste generate url for anchor tag 'Get price!'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a type="button" id="get-price" class="btn btn-success button-get-price" 
                    href="<%= asset_path('price.txt') %>">Get price!</a>
```

Should be....

```
<%= link_to "Get Price", public_path("price.txt"), id: "get-price", class: "btn btn-success button-get-price" %>
```

If you wanted to use a *button*:

```
<%= button_to "Get Price", public_path("price.txt"), method: :get, id: "get-price", class: "btn btn-success button-get-price" %>
```

---

1. Use *Rails [helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers.html)* wherever you can (this helps maintain compatibility)
2. You're using [`asset_path`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper/asset_path) to reference a file in the `/public` directory

---

Rails runs from the "public" directory.

If you have a file stored inside it, you'll need to reference it directly (either with the direct url: `yoururl.com/public.txt` or with `public_path`, which is relative).

-

Although the *assets* are also loaded from the `public` dir (when you "precompile" them, the ____ assets are put into `public/assets`), using [`asset_path`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper/asset_path) will *only* look in what's defined as the "asset" directories.

Thus, if you want to call a file in the *public* directory, you'll not be able to use `asset_path` - rather `public_path`.

---

## Notes

**Helpers**

In regards your *link*, you need to realize that [Rails' helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers.html) (of which [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) and [`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) are but two) just output HTML.

Whilst it may seem laborious to use these in your views, the benefits far outweigh the cost -- they provide access to all the latest HTML constructs.

This is important because of instead of writing...

```
<a href="....">Your Link</a>
```

... and finding that the `<a>` tag has changed spec, you can use...

```
<%= link_to "Your Link" ... %>
```

... and have the HTML updates provided in the next release of Rails.

It makes your application run with dynamic values, rather than having to manually code up every single element - making maintenance a huge pain.

--

**Static Pages**

It looks like you're also following a tutorial with `static_pages`.

You'll be MUCH better served adding a model & database to support this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :static_pages, path: "", only: [:show, :index, :edit, :update], path_names: {edit: "manager", update: "manager"} do
   get :manager, on: :collection
end
resources :sessions, path: "", only: [:new, :create, :destroy], path_names: {new: "signin", create: "signin", destroy: "signout"}

#app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :get_page, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

   def index
      @pages = StaticPage.all
   end

   def edit
   end

   def update
      redirect_to @page if @page.update
   end

   def show
   end

   def destroy
      redirect_to pages_root_path if @page.destroy
   end

   private

   def get_page
      @page = StaticPage.find params[:id]
   end
end

#app/models/static_page.rb
class StaticPage < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

You'll have to accompany this with a data table:

```
$ rails g migrations CreateStaticPages

#db/migrate/create_static_pages______.rb
class CreateStaticPages < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      create_table :static_pages do |t|
         t.string :title
         t.text :body
         t.timestamps
      end
   end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

Comment: One more great and detailed answer from you :) It helped to me, thank you! I'll go to see into information and advices what you gave me :)